# ActiveRecord: How to order and retrieve records in a greatest-n-per-group situation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, greatest-n-per-group

I'm stuck with a classic **greatest-n-per-group** problem, where a cat can have many kittens, but I'm usually just interested in the youngest.

I *already do know* how to build a `scope` and a `has_one` relation for the `Cat`.

My question: Is there a way to...

1. list all cats' names together with their youngest kittens' names...
2. while at the same time ordering them by their respective youngest kitten's name...

...using just a *single SELECT* under the hood?

What I got so far:

```rb
class Cat < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :kittens

  has_one :youngest_kitten, -> { merge(Kitten.youngest) }, foreign_key: :cat_id, class_name: :Kitten

  scope :with_youngest_kittens, lambda {
                                joins(:kittens)
                                  .joins(Kitten.younger_kittens_sql("cats.id"))
                                  .where(younger_kittens: { id: nil })
                              }
end

class Kitten
  belongs_to :cat
  scope :youngest, lambda {
    joins(Kitten.younger_kittens_sql("kittens.cat_id"))
      .where(younger_kittens: { id: nil })
  }

  def self.younger_kittens_sql(cat_field_name)
    %{
      LEFT OUTER JOIN kittens AS younger_kittens
      ON younger_kittens.cat_id = #{cat_field_name}
        AND younger_kittens.created_at > kittens.created_at
    }
  end
end
```

When I run `Cat.with_latest_kittens.order('kittens.name').map(&:name)` everything looks fine: I get all the cats' names with just a single SELECT.

But when I run `Cat.with_latest_kittens.order('kittens.name').map {|cat| cat.youngest_kitten.name}`, I get the right result too, but a superfluous additional SELECT per cat is executed. Which is just logical, because the `with_youngest_kittens` doesn't know it should populate `youngest_kitten`. Is there a way to tell it or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding an [includes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#includes) to your `:with_youngest_kittens` scope will fix the problem. Try changing the scope to

```
  scope :with_youngest_kittens, lambda {
    includes(:youngest_kitten)
      .joins(:kittens)
      .joins(Kitten.younger_kittens_sql("cats.id"))
      .where(younger_kittens: { id: nil })
  }
```

This should prevent Rails from making a separate database query for every kitten.

Comment: Yes, thank you!  That's _almost_ what I wanted (And I think it's close enough, so I'll use it).
It still produces one superfluous SELECT: The initial SELECT produced by `Cat.with_latest_kittens` should actually already be able to provide all the fields we need, but your `includes` adds a follow-up-`FROM kittens`-SELECT using the cat IDs retrieved in the first as parameters for `WHERE kittens.cat_id IN (...)`.
That is still much better than one extra SELECT _per cat_! ❤️

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that produces no extra SELECT, however it is quite **ugly**, so I'll actually go for [localarrow's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74321945/activerecord-how-to-order-and-retrieve-records-in-a-greatest-n-per-group-situat/74326517#74326517) as it's more readable!

I thought I'd still post it for the sake of completeness (If someone needs the few ms extra performance):

First I add custom tailored select fields for each kitten column to the `Cat.with_youngest_kitten` scope:

```rb
scope :with_youngest_kittens, lambda {
                                kitten_columns = Kitten
                                  .column_names
                                  .map { |column_name| "kittens.#{column_name} AS `youngest_kittens.#{column_name}`" }
                                  .join(', ')

                                joins(:kittens)
                                  .joins(Kitten.latest_outer_join_sql("cats.id"))
                                  .where(later_kittens: { id: nil })
                                  .select("cats.*, #{kitten_columns}")
                              }
```

Then I override the `has_one youngest_kitten` relation with a method, that retrieves those custom selects and calls super if no data has been retrieved:

```rb
def youngest_kitten
    return super if self[:'youngest_kittens.id'].nil?

    kitten_hash = Hash[Kitten.column_names.collect { |column_name| [column_name, self[:"youngest_kittens.#{column_name}"]] }]
    kitten_hash[:cat] = self
    Kitten.new(kitten_hash)
end
```